# VB.NET Try Catch with multiple Catch blocks

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, exception

This is a really odd issue. We have a Try Catch with multiple Catch blocks. The first Catch block has no code, just a comment.

```
Try
  'Some Code
Catch ex As ThreadAbortException
  'Do Nothing
Catch ex As Exception
  HandleException(ex)
End Try
```

If an exception other than a ThreadAbortException is thrown, it is caught by the second Catch, as expected. However, when stepping through code in VS2010, the ex object is Nothing in that case. So far, we have found two ways to "fix" this issue.

Fix 1:
Rename the first exception variable.

```
Try
  'Some Code
Catch tex As ThreadAbortException
  'Do Nothing
Catch ex As Exception
  HandleException(ex)
End Try
```

Fix 2: Add any line of code to the first Catch block.

```
Try
  'Some Code
Catch ex As ThreadAbortException
  Dim i As Integer = 1
Catch ex As Exception
  HandleException(ex)
End Try
```

The code in HandleException seems to still function properly if it's run, in any of the above cases. Is this a bug in Visual Studio or debugger?  Or are we missing something here and the first block of code above is invalid?

This is all being done in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Are you stepping through the code in release mode?

Comment: +1. Good question, a rare gem on StackOverflow.

Comment: This debugger bug looks fixed in VS2012.  Do make sure that you've got SP1 installed, it fixes many debugger bugs.

Comment: We do have SP1 installed. We also have VS2012, but are still using VS2010 for most development. If this works in VS2012, that would really confirm this being a VS2010 bug.

Comment: Wow! You gained 90 reputation with a simple question :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Teejay has the correct answer.

However, if your `Catch` block is empty it makes no sense at all to handle this exception. You just want to prevent the last block from catching it. You *can* use your method – but consider that having an empty `Catch` block is normally inacceptable: exceptions should either not be caught, or should be handled properly; swallowing them silently must be seen as a bug. Your case is an exception to this rule but as such it needs to be documented in code since it will confuse careful maintainers otherwise.

Well, VB has a special idiom for exactly this situation:

```
Try
    ' …
Catch ex As Exception When Not TypeOf ex Is ThreadAbortException
    ' Only executed if `ex` isn’t a ThreadAbortException
End Try
```

This code doesn’t catch `ThreadAbortException` at all, which is the right thing to do if you don’t want to handle it: `ThreadAbortException` **cannot** be swallowed so even when you catch it, it will be rethrown at the end of the `Catch` block.

Note that this is fundamentally different from SysDragon’s answer which uses a conventional `If` statement while the code here uses a special clause in the `Catch` statement as a filter.

Comment: There is a lot of VB that is "special".

Comment: This is a wonderful syntax which I didn't know before. Anyway, it's importanto to notice that this behaves different from Dan's code, in fact it does not catch `ThreadAbortException` that is thrown out from `Try...Catch` and must be handled externally to avoid the  program to crash.

Comment: @Teejay No, it behaves the same: `ThreadAbortException` **cannot** be caught. If you catch it, it will simply be rethrown. I should probably state this explicitly in my answer.

Comment: This is great. This is really what we want to accomplish (since we cannot swallow the ThreadAbortException). This is a much cleaner way of doing what we want to do.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Mhhh, not really clear. In Dan's code, the `ThreadAbortEx` is **caught and swallowed**.  As you wrote in your edit, with `When Not ...` the `ThreadAbortEx` is **not caught at all** instead. Happy that this is what Dan was looking for, but IMHO the two blocks act differently. Am I missing something? Help me understand.

Comment: Upvoting your answer for the great contribute, though not entirely pertinent.

Comment: @Teejay That’s exactly the point: in Dan’s code, the `ThreadAbortEx` is *not* swallowed, even if it looks like it is. But after the end of the `Catch` block it’s implicitly rethrown – just try it yourself! My code and Dan’s are exactly the same as long as Dan’s `Catch` block is empty.

Comment: Oh! Really? I'll give it a try tomorrow!

Comment: Actually I tried Dan's code on .net 3.5 (our default), throwing a `ThreadAbortException` in the `Try` block and it is being **swallowed**. If I execute your code instead, VS debugger pauses the program and shows me *ThreadAbortException was unhandled by user code*. So I believe the two blocks act different.

Comment: Your code is more like the following: `Try` / `'Some Code` / `Catch ex As Exception` / `If (TypeOf ex Is ThreadAbortException) Then Throw ex Else HandleException(ex)` / `End Try`

Comment: @Teejay No. Your code is doing something wrong. I can absolutely guarantee that. What you are saying contradicts the MSDN, the platform standard and my own tests. Please post your code on http://ideone.com/ or a similar site.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Unfortunately, it seems that ideone.com doesn't support `Catch When` (they are using Mono, see here http://ideone.com/GPLcd8). Anyway, Dan's code runs smoothly and **swallows** the exception like I expected it to do: http://ideone.com/86KNPB (I used an ArgumentEx for convenience).

Comment: @Teejay Aargh! We’re talking specifically about `ThreadAbortException` here! You cannot just substitute that with `ArgumentException`. **Of course** that is swallowed – otherwise `Catch` would be totally broken. `ThreadAbortException` gets special treatment, that’s the whole point. Here you go (C#, since Mono’s VB support sucks as you’ve noticed yourself): http://ideone.com/WqnJ8b

Comment: @KonradRudolph Oh! Thanks for your explanation, I missed that! Actually, in this specific case *you're right*. But *speaking generally* your code's behavior does not match Dan's one. We misunderstood each other.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be a VS' debugger bug.

**PROOF**

If you write:

```
Try
    Throw New InvalidOperationException("MESSAGE")
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    'Do Nothing
Catch ex As Exception
    Debug.WriteLine(ex)
End Try
```

and you look at `ex` it evaluates to `Nothing` in *Quickwatch mode*

***BUT***

in the console the program correctly prints `System.InvalidOperationException: MESSAGE`

Answer (score -2):

Ok let me elaborate...

It appears that you must have a "result" in each catch.  If you simply want nothing to happen for a specific catch, don't include it, or have it move to a different place in your code.

```
Try
   'Some Code
Catch ex As ThreadAbortException
   'Do something(ex: HandleExceptionSub())
Catch ex As Exception
   HandleException(ex)
End Try
```

If you "catch" an exception you have to do something with it.

EDIT:

I have also found this information you that can help further inform you about the way a try catch works:

Multiple Catch Blocks

A try block can throw multiple exceptions, which can handle by using multiple catch blocks. Remember that more specialized catch block should come before a generalized one. Otherwise the compiler will show a compilation error.  [Multiple Catch Blocks](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rajeshvs/ExceptionHandlinginCSharp11282005051444AM/ExceptionHandlinginCSharp.aspx)

It isn't a "Bug" with the Debugger.  The debugger is meant to help you find and handle all exceptions.

EDIT:
Seems that this exception could be avoided completely from what I read in another post.  And it seems that it would be better to avoid the exception instead of not dealing with it.
[Handling ThreadAbortException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602494/threadabortexception-vs-graceful-event-handle-exit-in-c-sharp)

EDIT:
Just found more information on multiple catch blocks in try. This is from MSDN and states that a catch blocks after a blank catch block will never be reached...[Try Catch Finally Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
Further proof that this is NOT a bug but the expected functionality to enforce handling all exceptions in your code.

EDIT:
To set some people in the comments straight I have created a very simple test program to see if this is indeed a bug.  My findings are that the catch blocks work perfectly.  Seems that following the MSDN documented way of creating a Try Catch with multiple Catch blocks works as they say it does.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("textBox1", "TextBox can not be empty");
            }
            else
            {
                MyString(textBox1.Text);
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
        {
            //nothing
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private int MyString(string text)
    {
        return int.Parse(text);
    }
```

I created a simple form with a button and a textbox.  If the textbox is empty I throw an ArgumentNullException, and in the "MyString" I parse a string to an integer which throws a "FormatException".  Having a blank catch block, which is NOT the right way to handle a "caught" exception does indeed work.  So as far as I can see this is not a bug.  Apparently the only thing I can agree with Teejay and Konrad about is that you can NOT catch and handle the ThreadAbortException using the try catch method. Konrad's solution is the best way to code your try catch.

Comment: Probably, he simply want to silently "suppress" all ThreadAbortEx.

Comment: To silently "suppress" the exception you still have to "handle" it.  If you want to not "handle" it, fully silence it then don't "catch" it.

Comment: If you don't catch an exception, the program crashes... Am I missing something?

Comment: So your program is generating an exception that must be handled.  If this is an exception that can not be resolved by adding extra logic to the routines causing the exception, then you must handle the exception.  Many times when I have an exception in my code I try to build logic to avoid reoccurrences of that exception.  In rare cases I have to generate a try catch that will do something when this exception is "caught".  Bottom line is, "If you catch an exception you must handle it in some way."

Comment: Teejay is correct. We want to silently suppress the ThreadAbortException. With just Catch ex As Exception, you also catch ThreadAbortException, which we do not want to handle. I think SysDragon was onto the right solution below.

It still seems like a debugger bug though.

Comment: Very hard to believe that this is a bug with the debugger, especially when the way a try catch is designed is meant to handle exceptions that are caught.  I also tried searching for KB articles where others had this same problem and a fix for it.  However I found none, and if this were a bug I find it very unlikely that no one else would have experienced it.  This leads me to believe that it is not a bug.  In SysDragon's post he is showing how you could handle the exception "silently".  You can handle the exception in your "HandleException" sub by using an If Then to respond, or not respond.

Comment: SysDragon solution is only a different way to NOT handle ThreadAbortException. In fact, if `ex` is of type `ThreadAbortException`, his code do nothing, exactly like Dan's code. Anyway you're talking about (doubtful) "Good practice of coding" and **you're NOT answering Dan's question** (*and i'm downvoting your answer*). As @Hans Passant turned out, this has been fixed in VS2012, so it's very likely to be a bug.

Comment: Good coding practice or not, he is trying to use exception handling to not handle an exception.  Try Catch is designed to "handle" exceptions, whether silently or not.  And SysDragon's response is still handling the exception.  It just does it "silently".  If the exception happens and is not of type "ThreadAbortException" it moves to the routine.  This is still handling the exception.  Does not matter how you slice it, if you catch an exception you have to handle it.

Comment: I found this other post on how to handle this exception.  Just letting the thread abort is not the ideal way to handle stopping it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602494/threadabortexception-vs-graceful-event-handle-exit-in-c-sharp

Comment: What part of *"you're NOT answering Dan's question"* you did not understand? The question is *"Is this a bug in Visual Studio or debugger? Or are we missing something here and the first block of code above is invalid?"*. The block of code above actually IS valid VB.net. So you're answer is unconstructive in this context.

Comment: Why not let Dan make that decision. You obviously have an agenda here. Not sure what it is but good luck with that

Comment: Virtually all the information in this post is wrong (except for the last paragraph). This *is* a bug in the debugger, and you do *not* have to have code in the handler block. And lastly, your comment suggesting to use `GoTo` here is simply atrocious. There are very few (if any) valid uses for `GoTo`. This isn’t one.

Comment: Yes you are right about not using goto. But I challenge you to prove that my post is filled with wrong information. There still isnt any proof that this is a bug. Show me proof that it is a bug.

Comment: @jforward5 Teejay has posted the proof. In addition, a look into the [VB language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234437.aspx) (§10.10.1.2) will show you that `Catch` blocks are allowed to be empty. In fact, no need to look there: if it were different, the compiler would flag this as an error.

Comment: True they can be empty.  But that doesn't make this a bug.  And as for proof, Teejay's code only proves that the try catch is doing what it is designed to do, capture and "handle" exceptions.  The fact that it doesn't provide information for the subsequent exceptions in the list of catches shows that it is designed to handle the exceptions, not to "sweep" them under the rug.

Comment: The program actually provide information about subsequent exceptions. BUT the VS' debugger does not. And this has been fixed in VS2012.

Comment: Where is the proof.  You can say "it is a bug" until you are blue in the face but with out an article from MS, specifically a KB article detailing the problem and the fix, I can't see it as a bug.  Especially when it enforces proper coding and exception handling...

Comment: @jforward5 Read Teejay’s answer again: It is a bug in the debugger because the debugger shows the `ex` object as having the value `Nothing` when in fact it observably has a different value. The debugger shows a wrong value. That is a bug. There doesn’t have to be a KB article about this for it to be a bug: Microsoft isn’t omniscient, they don’t know about all the bugs, and it’s possible that nobody has noticed this one before.

Comment: I know that they don't know about all bugs, no one does.  However it is documented by MS that this is the way the debugger is to function.  So in my opinion if it is documented then it isn't a bug...

Comment: @jforward5 That is not what the MSDN article says at all. It says that when you have a *nonspecific* `Catch` clause (i.e. simply `Catch` without `ex As SomeExceptionType`), then subsequent `Catch` clauses will not be reached. However, that would also be a *compile error*. Furthermore, even if the MSDN *did* state that it would contradict the passage from the standard that I have referred to and would thus be irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, still doesn't eliminate the fact that you must do something in each block.  Empty doesn't work.  It IS the WAY it was designed.

Comment: If it was the way it is designed, it should give a compile-time error. But it doesn't. And, once more, this is not what the question's about.

Comment: @jforward5 You are simply wrong, and the the Teejay’s code, the MSDN *and* the language standard trivially tell you that. If you are so convinced that you are right, then the only right thing to do is to devise a test for your hypothesis: write a code that fulfils all our criteria from the comments, that contains an empty `Catch` block followed by a less-specific non-empty `Catch` block and see whether the second block is executed. This is called [falsification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability) and so far you refuse to use it.

Comment: I tested this as you suggested and did not find it to be a bug. I did not see the same results that Teejay saw.

Comment: @jforward5: When comments sections spans more than 1 page (like this one), it is most likely an indicator that's not doing anything but wasting people's time and nerves. It does not matter who is right and who is wrong. Source: some experience being a member of SO. Also, based on previous experience, you better not try to argue with Konrad, as well as some other members of SO. :)

Comment: Not arguing, I apologize if it comes off that way, or looks that way.